# how can i identify the protocol of a connection from a pcap file

Tags: python, sockets, networking, tcp

I am trying to scan a pcap file and count the number of packets for every protocol in the file.
Assuming that i can use port number as the identify method, i still have a problem when looking at a specific packet determine to what protocol that packet belongs.
The reason is that i don't know on what port should i look - source port or destination port
On a given connection, let's say HTTP, client to server packets will have source port(some source port, maybe 60000) and  destination port 80, however, server to client packets will have a destination port 60000 and source port 80.
So, on a given packet how can i know the protocol it belongs?

Answer (score 0):

It looks from the question that you are just trying to count packet that have (src.port == 80 || dst.port == 80). For example you say you know that 80 is port used for HTTP in one of the directions.

In this case you can just use the built-in tshark utility that comes with Wireshark and pipe it to wc(assuming you use linux)  as follows:

```
tshark -r /tmp/soap.cap  -T fields -d tcp.port==18083,echo -e echo.data | wc -l
```

or

```
tshark -r /tmp/soap.cap  -T fields -d tcp.port==18083,echo -e echo.port | wc -l
```

Note that this will count even TCP packets like Syn even if those are not HTTP packets per se.

If you want to access only HTTP packets, you can use the following:

```
tshark -r /tmp/soap.cap  -T fields -d tcp.port==18083,http -e http.request.version | wc -w
```

Note that this last one assumes that the output per line is one word. If this is not the case you can easily filter out empty lines with other Linux utilities.